# How does java treat the input of the "enter" key on a keyboard

Tags: java, eclipse, validation, java.util.scanner, system.in

hi complete noob in programming and am trying to do some user input validation using a System.in scanner
i am trying to find a way to detect when a user inputs nothing and just presses the enter key but it seems like java doesn't acknowledge the enter key as an input because when i run the program and press enter the text cursor on the console just moves to a new line and the program acts like it is still waiting for an input so how would i detect when the enter key is pressed?

side question is pressing the enter key the same as no input or is it classes as input?

Comment: You didn't include code. The enter key adds a newline, which is whitespace. What you're asking the `Scanner` to read determines whether whitespace is important or skipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using an instance of `Scanner(System.in),` pressing the enter key, `scanner.nextLine()` without a previous input should return an empty string.